# python best practice of dealing with huge number of objects

Tags: python

I am building a code in python which collecting huge number of objects and have a statistics periodically of those objects
every object has a timestamp which represnet when it collected , i need to have in memory only the last 30 seconds objects and delete the rest (30 seconds as example)
so the normal psudocode will be like this

```
thread loop
while True
   for elem in list
      if now - elem.timestamp > 30
          list.remove(elem)
   sleep(30)
```

what is the best practice of doing such things

edit :
the app is acting as a receiver of object that comming from streaming server the load is very high may reach billion/hour and the app accepting every object from the server
i will simplify the object with two members (timestamp and value) the server should have the min, max , avg, etc of all objects which their timestamp is not more than 30 seconds old and remove the rest from memory

Comment: First step to best practice: add colons to `for`, `if` and `while` lines.

Comment: How are you taking in the data? Accumulating and processing 30-second chunks seems feasible depending on the size of the data and the capacity of your system.

Comment: What is a "huge number"?

Comment: @Jay and roganjosh
the app is a streaming receiver which accept data comming from streaming source , i think i will have billion of object per hour , and i need the last 30 seconds objects to be active in memory

Comment: @KlausD. it is a psudocode  bro

Comment: That's quite a serious incoming load. I not sure you'll be able to handle it with vanilla python like this. You shouldn't be modifying a list while iterating over it, you'd need to rebuild the list periodically but I don't think it will be responsive on that scale. You'll probably need to look into frameworks that can handle that volume, but we don't know what exactly you're trying to do in the broader sense.

Comment: For maintaining a fixed-length list you can use a deque: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects

Comment: @Jay this is not a fixed list , as i dont know the number of objects that i will receive it from the server for the next 30 seconds